# July 2013 Breaking Changes, Graph API post search with or without access token on Android

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-graph-api, search

My question would be an extension of the question
[July 2013 breaking changes: Graph API post search with or without access token?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17163532/july-2013-breaking-changes-graph-api-post-search-with-or-without-access-token)

I have an Android application which uses the Facebook SDK for Android v3.0.
How could I check that all my requests uses the user access token for Graph API post?

In all my requests I check the status of the active session:

```
Session.getActiveSession() != null && Session.getActiveSession().isOpened()
```

and pass the active session to the request Constructor (example for a Place request):

```
Request placeRequest = Request.newGraphPathRequest(
                    Session.getActiveSession(), 
                    placeId, 
                    requestCallback
);
```

Is this enough to add the user access token to the request and so being compliant with the July 2013 Breaking Changes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The check for the *Session* to be not-null and opened grants that each request created using that *Session* has a valid access token.